# Pandas DF SQL DELETE FROM

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sql-delete

I'm trying to set up a script that will allow SQL query and transformations to a pandas df. I'm running into an issue though when trying to use the DELETE FROM statement. I currently have something like this:

```
import os
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import pandasql as ps

csv_file_path = 's3://bucket/folder/test.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(csv_file_path)

sql_mod = '''DELETE FROM df WHERE opt_out = 1'''
df1 = ps.sqldf(sql_mod, locals())
print(df1)
```

And the table I'm reading in from s3 looks like this

```
  customer    cust_id      phone_nm          addr          date        order  opt_out
0     John   13251236  123-456-7890  2.893746e+10  8.760298e+07    298746746        0
1     Alex  234623476  234-567-8901  2.834760e+08  9.824770e+09      8746972        0
2   Amanda     151351  345-678-9012  2.090000e+14  9.750000e+11   9712975917        1
3    Carol    4236246  456-789-0123  9.284750e+07  7.346908e+10   9857897947        0
4     Carl   73457357  567-890-1234  2.934757e+09  3.746972e+08     97234967        1
5    Karen   15313513      678-9012  2.948769e+10  2.348760e+06      2436ou2        1
8    Scott    2573567  901-234-5678  9.723497e+07  9.723461e+07   9f29h34tin        0
```

But my delete statement is returning a NULL DF it seems. Is there a way to run SQL DELETEs and INSERTs using pandas df that retains the standard SQL format?

Comment: what kind of DF do you want your delete statement to return?

Comment: I'm hoping for a pandas df that just has all the opt outs dropped so that I can write the df as a csv to s3.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `select` statement rather than a `delete` statement.

I'm not sure the details of your SQL implementation, but `delete` is generally destructive - I'd check to see whether your data still looks the way you expect it to (i.e. does it still have as many rows as it did before).

To get a DataFrame with all the opt outs dropped, use `where`:

```
sql_mod = '''SELECT * FROM df WHERE opt_out = 1'''
```

Comment: I get you there, but I also need the DELETE to remove the opted out people permanently in the future.

Comment: I would use the select first and then delete in that case!